# oscommerce xml feed

Tags: oscommerce

I have never worked with oscommerce before, but the custom I have worked with prveiously (on Wordpress and pure PHP) is asking me to add XML feed to his oscommerce website.

Can you, please, guid me:
1) is there any existing plugin/module to use?
or
2) should I do xml feed by myself?

I need website to take date from the follwong xmls:
http://www.atsdistribution.co.uk/feeds/Xml_All_Products.aspx
and
http://www.atsdistribution.co.uk/feeds/Xml_All_Stock.aspx

and to update prodcuts automatically.

I was looking into google and I havenot found the sollution for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no addons that I am aware of that will take XML feed and populate product or inventory.
You will have to do the following:

1. Using CURL or some other way first get this XML file on your site server.
2. Then create a csv from this XML.
3. Call easy populate( AN addon ) to populate your products.

This will save your efforts for step3.

Comment: How to make this process repeat once a day (or any other time)?

Comment: Can I use these steps automatically one a day or I have to import csv into system manually all the time?

Comment: you will have to use cron and schedule your script.